# Lambda function with map where key is tuple and value is double

Tags: c++, c++11, stdtuple

I have a map, filled with values:

```
std::map<std::tuple<int, int, double>, double> Cache;
```

When the size of map is greater than 100, I want to delete/erase only the map elements whose values in the key tuple are all more than 10.  Here is how it can be done with `while` and `if`:

```
if (Cache.size() > 100) {
    auto it = Cache.begin();
    while (it != Cache.end()) {
        auto myCache = it->first;
        auto actualX = std::get<0>(myCache);
        auto actualY = std::get<1>(myCache);
        auto actualZ = std::get<2>(myCache);
        if (abs(actualX) > 10 || abs(actualY) > 10) || abs(actualZ) > 10)) {
            Cache.erase(it++);
        } else {
            it++;
        }
    }
}
```

How one can implement the same behavior using [`find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) (or other function) and lambda function?

#### Update2

After going through the wikipedia link provided in the comment section i have implemented the following code, but its giving an compiler error :(

```
Cache.erase(std::remove_if(Cache.begin(),
                                 Cache.end(),
                                 [=](auto &T) -> bool {
                                     auto myCache = T->first;
                                     auto actualX = std::get<0>(myCache);
                                     auto actualY = std::get<1>(myCache);
                                     return std::abs(actualX) > 10|| std::abs(actualY) > 10 || std::abs(actualZ) > 10;
                                 }),
                  Cache.end());
```

### update 3

The above cannot be used with map ;(

Comment: `Cache.erase(it++);` is wrong, it should be `it = Cache.erase(it);`.

Comment: Unfortunately `std::map` does not support `std::remove_if` so I think  loop is a simplest solution here

Comment: @Quentin it is not wrong, it is an alternative

Comment: @Slava hmm. Is the increment strictly sequenced before the function call?

Comment: @Quentin Yes.  All function parameters are evaluated before the function is entered.

Comment: @NathanOliver alright then. I'm leaving this for the next people to fall for it. But that begs the question, why do `erase` functions return the next iterator then?

Comment: @Slava : I guess using find_if i could implement the condition as lambda function and the returned iterator can be then deleted.

Comment: It would use `const auto &myCache = it->first;` though for 2 ints and one double it could be not necessary.

Comment: Anyone here mentioned the Erase-remove idiom? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom

Comment: @Quentin `erase` didn't used to and this was the one line solution pre C++11.  Now that it returns the next iterator there isn't a need to use it but you still can.

Comment: @vinaycool yea that possible but I do not see much improvement. Actually let me try

Comment: @TuanDT Yep, and you can't use it on associative containers

Comment: I know its not answering the question but it's a really bad idea to use a double in a key

Comment: If you missed the second comment in this section, please read the documentation of [`std::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) where in the notes it is stated: *"These algorithms cannot be used with associative containers such as std::set and std::map because ForwardIt does not dereference to a MoveAssignable type (the keys in these containers are not modifiable)"*. Have you tried any of the answers you already got?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::find_if` with predicate:

```
auto pred = []( const auto &t ) { 
    return std::abs( std::get<0>( t. ) ) > 10 || 
           std::abs( std::get<1>( t ) ) > 10 || 
           std::fabs( std::get<2>( t ) ) > 10.0 ); };

for( auto it = Cache.begin(); true; it = Cache.erase( it ) ) {
     it = std::find_if( it, Cache.end(), pred );
     if( it == Cache.end() ) break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like following should work

```
namespace myUtility {

template< typename C, typename P >
  void custom_erase_if( C& items, const P& predicate ) {
    for( auto it = items.begin(); it != items.end(); ) {
      if( predicate(*it) ) it = items.erase(it);
      else ++it;
    }
  }
}
```

Then,

```
  myUtility::custom_erase_if( Cache, [](const auto& x) {
     auto myCache = x.first;
            auto actualX = std::get<0>(myCache);
            auto actualY = std::get<1>(myCache);
            auto actualZ = std::get<2>(myCache);
            return ( std::abs(actualX) > 10 || 
                    std::abs(actualY) > 10  || 
                    std::abs(actualZ) > 10) ) ; 
    } );
```

Comment: I really find annoying style with `if( cond ) return true; else return false;`

Comment: @Slava Yeah me too. :|

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is arrange the map so that the elements you want are at the back of the map.

```
struct over_10 {
  bool operator()( std::tuple<int, int, double> const& t) const {
    return
      (std::get<0>(t)>10 || std::get<0>(t)<-10) // min int doesn't like abs
   && (std::get<1>(t)>10 || std::get<1>(t)<-10)
   && fabs(std::get<2>(t))>10.0;
  }
};
template<class Split>
struct split_order {
  template<class Lhs, class Rhs>
  bool operator()( Lhs const& lhs, Rhs const& rhs ) const {
    auto split = Split{};
    return std::tie( split(lhs), lhs ) < std::tie( split(rhs), rhs );
  }
};
using split_on_10_order = split_order<over_10>;
```

what this does is it splits the sorting so that things that pass the `over_10` test are all ordered last.  Everything is ordered sensibly within each "split".

Now:

```
std::map<std::tuple<int, int, double>, double, split_on_10_order> Cache;

auto it = Cache.lower_bound(
  std::make_tuple(
    std::numeric_limits<int>::min(),
    std::numeric_limits<int>::min(),
    std::numeric_limits<double>::min()
  )
);

Cache.erase( it, Cache.end() );
```

and done.

This takes about O(lg n) time to find the split, then O(m) to delete the m elements that should be deleted.

Comment: Also you assumed that OP does not care about order and can change sorting arbitrarily,  I doubt this is a case, OP may want to use `std::unordered_map` if he does not care of order.

Comment: @Slava Ok, fixed it with numeric limits min.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as pointed by Slava, `std::remove_if` can't be used with maps.

I think your solution (a loop to erase the unwanted elements) isn't bad, but if you want to use the algorithm library, the best that come in my mint is use `std::copy_if()` to **move** the elements you want preserve in a temporary map and following swap the two maps.

I mean... something as

```
   if ( Cache.size() > 100 )
    {
      std::map<std::tuple<int, int, double>, double> CacheTmp;

      std::copy_if(std::make_move_iterator(Cache.begin()),
                   std::make_move_iterator(Cache.end()),
                   std::inserter(CacheTmp, CacheTmp.end()),
                   [] (auto const & p)
                     { return (std::abs(std::get<0>(p.first)) <= 10)
                           && (std::abs(std::get<1>(p.first)) <= 10)
                           && (std::abs(std::get<2>(p.first)) <= 10.0); });

      Cache.swap(CacheTmp);
    }
```

Unfortunately that `auto` parameter for lambda functions are available only starting from C++14, so if you need of a C++11 solution, instead of `auto const & p`, your lambda should receive a `std::pair<td::tuple<int, int, double>, double> const & p`